# Palindrome check in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello to everyone on stack.

I am trying to make a python program capable of searching for palindromes.

If my inputs were simply words to evaluate, I would have had no problem writing the code

```
def ispalindrome(word):
    return word == word[::-1]
```

but I am trying to do more than this.

I would like to check if a string 'contains' a palindrome

for example,

```
>>>ispalindrome('rapparee')
rappar
```

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Every string contains a palindrome of length 1. What's the minimum length for you to consider a palindrome a palindrome?

Comment: So you're looking for the largest palindrome too? Why wouldn't it return `appa`? What have you tried?

Comment: @Aran-Fey@Sayse I am indeed looking for the largest palindrome. I have not a single clue how to iterate forward through the string while also iterating backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get all substrings, ordered by length and then iterate through them:

```
# Get a dictionary of length : [substrings]

def get_all_substrings(input_string):
    length = len(input_string)
    substrings = [input_string[i:j+1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i,length)]

    length_substring_dict = dict()
    for substring in substrings:
        dictionary_entry = length_substring_dict.get(len(substring), [])
        dictionary_entry.append(substring)
        length_substring_dict[len(substring)] = dictionary_entry

    return length_substring_dict


def ispalindrome(word):
    return word == word[::-1]

# Iterate through the substrings, starting with the longest and check for palindromes.
def has_palindrome(word):
    for length, substring_list in sorted(get_all_substrings(word).items(), reverse=True):
        for substring in substring_list:
            if ispalindrome(substring):
                return substring
```